# Predict a class that is not in the training dataset

Tags: conv-neural-network, classification

Suppose we have five classes: Dog, Cat, Banana, Apple, and Tree.
If we train a CNN with all and want to predict the class of unknown images like an image of "Car", the model gives one of the classes each time.

Can you please tell me how we can tell the model if the data is not part of the training dataset, say "I did not detect the class" or something like that?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you handle a "none of these" class in a CNN](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192426/how-do-you-handle-a-none-of-these-class-in-a-cnn)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem either by adding a neutral class or by transforming your problem into a multi-classification and adding thresholding.

- for the **neutral class**, you have to go back to the labeling phase and add some  **random image** (be careful that this random image does not contain an image of the other class, for example in your case an image of a dog because this would hurt your model) with the label **"other"**.
- in case of **multi-classification**, you don't need additional images, but you need to change the activation function of your classification layer (the last layer of your network), from **softmax** to **sigmoid**
  for exemple
  from :

*keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')*

to

*keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='sigmoid')*

The main difference between the sigmoid model and the softmax model is that the softmax model is guaranteed to contain values whose sum is equal to 1, whereas the output of the sigmoid model will contain values, each between 0 and 1.

So your model in this case learns to make an independent prediction of each class for example if the output is [0.7,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.8] if we take 0.6 as the threshold, then your model is almost sure that the image contains a dog and a tree, in the case we take for example 0.9 as the threshold this image does not contain any object of your 5 - classes so you can say "other".